# where is mscoree.dll in mono linux?

Tags: .net, linux, mono

In Windows, the mscoree.dll, is the start of a CLR app, but where is it or what is it in Mono Linux?

Answer (score 4):

There is no mscoree.dll in mono.

All the startup code is inside the `mono` executable.

Comment: @user1654475 If this answer helped you, you should click the check mark to the left to select it as the answer